# Using serializing an object in python for use with an XBee

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, ros, robotics

For a project I'm working on, I'm supposed to use XBee radio modules, which isn't super important, except that I have to read and write to their serial port in order to use them. I'm currently working with Python and ROS, so I'm attempting to send TransformStamped messages over the XBees.

My question is, unless I'm misunderstanding how Serial.read() and Serial.write() work, how can I tell how many bytes to read? I was planning on using Pickle to serialize the data into a string, and then sending that over the serial ports. Is there a better way that I've overlooked? Is there some sort of loop that would work to read data until the end of the pickled string is read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, serial.read() cannot tell you how many bytes to read. Either you have some prior knowledge as to how long the message is, or the data you send has some means of denoting the boundaries between messages.

Hint; knowing how long a message is is not enough, you also need to know whereabouts in the received byte stream a message has actually started. You don't know for sure that the bytes received are exactly aligned with the sent bytes: you may not have started the receiver before the transmitter, so they can be out of step.

With any serialisation one has to ask, is it self delimiting, or not? Google Protocol buffers are not. I don't think Pickle is either. ASN.1 BER is, at least to some extent. So is XML.

The point is that XBee modules are (assuming you're using the ones from Digi) just unreliable byte transports, so whatever you put through them has to be delimited in some way so that the receiving end knows when it has a complete message. Thus if you pickle or Google Protocol Buf your message, you need some other way of framing the serialised data so that the receiving end knows it has a complete message (i.e. it's seen the beginning *and* end). This can be as simple as some byte pattern (e.g. 0xffaaccee00112233) used to denote the end of one message and the beginning of the next, chosen so as to be unlikely to occur in the sent messages themselves. Your code at the receiving end would read and discard data until is saw that pattern, would then read subsequent data into a buffer until it saw that pattern again, and only then would it attempt to de-pickle / de-GPB the data back into an object.

With ASN.1 BER, the data stream itself incorporates effectively the same thing, saving you the effort. It uses tags, values and length fields to tell its decoders about the incoming data, and if the incoming data makes no sense to the decoder in comparison to the original schema, incorrectly framed data is easily ignored.

This kind of problem also exists on tcp sockets, though at least with those delivery is more or less guaranteed (the first bytes you receive are the first bytes sent). A Digimesh connection does not quite reach the same level of guaranteed delivery as a tcp socket, so something else is needed (like a framing byte pattern) for the receiving application to know that it is synchronised with the sender.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm not familiar with ASN.1 BER, but I might try encoding with XML instead of pickle. Thanks again!